# Is it "OK" to add JSP/Tomcat support to an existing LAMP web server?

Tags: php, linux, apache, jsp, tomcat

Is it possible to add JSP/Tomcat support to an existing LAMP web server? I never tried to do this before and was wondering if this was ok to do in a production environment or if it went against best practices.

I have a Debian webserver with a LAMP stack running Apache2. I have a few PHP websites but I would like to add a Java/JSP powered website like so:

```
/var/www/myphpsite
/var/www/myjspsite
/var/www/etc etc.
```

Thanks,
Jason

Comment: You'll probably have better luck with this over at [serverfault](http://serverfault.com/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There shouldn't be any inherent problems as long as you have the CPU and memory for it.  The Tomcat instances would be running in a separate process from Apache HTTP server.

Just connected apache to Tomcat with [mod_jk](http://tomcat.apache.org/connectors-doc) or [mod_proxy_ajp](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_proxy_ajp.html).

Answer (score 1):

Yes it's very OK. I do it all the time on high traffic sites where some components are PHP and others are Java based.

Make sure you also setup [mod_status](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_status.html) so you can monitor what the apache workers are working on.